# Centos installed, switch to gui, no internet connection

Tags: gui

I've installed CentOS 7 on a Dell PowerEdge R320. I did the minimal install and its starting up at the command line. Is there anyway to switch to the regular gui without reinstalling or a internet connection. I could load a file to a usb stick and go from there... Or would a complete re install be faster?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've installed the minimal CentOS install from the smallest ISO they have. In other words, you have the bare minimum you need to have a working system. For Linux gurus, this is called an OS. That being said, you have three options.

- Option 1: Get the `DVD` ISO and install it with the `GUI`.
- Option 2: Get the `netinstall` and don't forget to choose the `Gnome` Desktop Environment from the package list to install the `GUI`.
- Option 3: Get internet connection on the system and simply install it using `yum`.

I would suggest going with `option 3` as it is the easiest and possibly as simple as running

```
dhcpcd ens0p0
```

I would suggest checking the following [link](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-dhcp-configuring-client.html) if your network is configured as `DHCP`.

Answer (score 0):

a complete reinstall can be fast, from dvd onto an SSD I can do it in less than 1 hour: the first 5-10 minutes is booting dvd and getting through the install gui to the final ok click then about 20-30 minutes to install to the disk followed by the reboot and account & network setup and the little things.  For the install you would choose `server with gui` or `gnome desktop` as opposed to "minimal install".

with a minimal install you are I think at runlevel 3 or now known as multi-user.target.  To get to runlevel 5 full graphics you can do either `init 5` or `systemctl isolate graphical.target`.  However if you don't have that stuff installed, I don't know what would happen actually.

```
# this will return the current setting the OS runlevel is set to boot
# automatically.  I suspect a minimal install will put you to runlevel 3 having
# full network capability but no graphics which is systemd multi-user.target

systemctl get-default

# to set the runlevel to boot to full graphics full networking.

systemctl set-default graphical.target



# https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-7-how-to-install-gui/

# for an already installed system, have the centos7 install dvd (or usb)
 present as a repository so that you can basically carry on where the minimal
 install stopped.  You don't require networking to do this:

yum grouplist
yum groupinstall "Server with GUI"


# for a minimal install system this should work, but with the stuff you
# take for granted like networking, centos and EPEL repositories being
# available, not having to worry about dependencies and setting up repo's
# then a complete reinstall from dvd may be fast enough and less headache/risk.
```